# Curl fails to connect to localhost

Tags: 16.04

I have just upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 successfully. But now, if I try curl command, it gives an error message `curl: (7) failed to connect to locahost port 5984. Connection refused`.

I wanted to check couchdb error log but it was empty. I tried to reconfigure some files using `dpkg` but nothing worked.

I then removed `couchdb` and reinstalled it but it did not work too.

The hosts file looks ok:

```
127. 0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 mango      #host name
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. I think curl doesn't resolve 'localhost'.

Answer (score 2):

Which command are you using. Are you using localhost with curl? First check the output of the following:

```
curl -v localhost:5984
```

Most likely you would find an output similar to this:

```
Rebuilt URL to: localhost:5948/ 
Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
Trying ::1...
```

Most likely, curl is not able to resolve localhost. It switches to an IPv6 address of localhost and your couchdb is not listening for an IPv6 address. Change from localhost to 127.0.0.1.

```
curl 127.0.0.1:5984
```

Comment: Curl -v gives the same error

Comment: Of course it will give the same error, -v is just for verbose mode, so that you can see the details. Have you tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost? Because as I explained, curl is not being able to resolve localhost to 127.0.0.1.